# How to add hidden controls to a form (not programmatically)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I used a custom "skin" or w/e you may call it for uniquely designed forms in Visual Studio, to be accurate for VB.NET.

I decided to remove the custom form and the problem is that all controls are now hidden, but they still exist within the project.

Is there any way to make them visible in designer again, so I can add them to my new form.

Comment: We don't know anything about this custom skin (or "uniquely designed form") and we don't know how you "removed" it. These are key information to understand your situation and maybe help you with it.

Comment: They are known also as themes, heres a website with examples: http://leakplanet.blogspot.com/2014/07/visual-basic-75-net-themes.html

Comment: How did you remove the custom form?

Comment: Just removed the control, removed the control code from visual files and recompiled to project  to get rid of theme toolbox.

Comment: If you can undo those steps, then i suggest you hit `CTRL+A` , `CTRL+C` - to copy all controls, then on your new form, you hit `CTRL+V`- paste.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I closed Visual Studio after I did this, so the change history wasn't remembered.

Comment: How do you know the controls still exist in your project?

Comment: They are still shown in control properties tab, also the control code exists within the project itself without any issues.

Comment: If that's the case, they are contained in something. What does the designer show them to be contained in? You should be able to search on the control name and find in what section it shows `<SomeContainer>.Controls.Add(<yourControlName>)` this is assuming you mean code is referencing these controls without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check to Location of the missing controls , maybe it's outside bounds.